# I want get the min value collection from RDD ,but the min value is mutiple, How I can do this?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

My rdd data structer is like this:

```
(a,2) (a,2) (a,3) (a,3) (a,3) (a,4)
```

I want get the min value from the RDD like this:

```
(a,2) (a,2)
```

How I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can count objects:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(("a", 2), ("a", 2), ("a", 3), ("a", 3), ("a", 4))

val counts = rdd.map((_, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

and either `reduce`:

```
val min counts.reduce((x, y) => if (x._1._2 <= y._1._2) x else y)
```

or use `min`:

```
import scala.math.Ordering

val min = counts.min()(Ordering.by[((String, Int), Int), Int](_._1._2))
```

You can optionally follow this with replication step:

```
min match {
  case (x, n) => Seq.fill(n)(x)
}
```

If counts are not important just use `min` directly:

```
rdd.min()(Ordering.by[(String, Int), Int](_._2))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
case class Item(c: Char, i: Int)
val items = Array[Item](new Item('a', 2), new Item('a', 2), new Item('a', 3), new Item('a', 3), new Item('a', 3), new Item('a', 4), new Item('a', 6), new Item('a', 5))
val rdd = sc.makeRDD(items)
val minValue = rdd.map(_.i).min()
val result = rdd.filter(item => item.i == minValue)
```